# Displaying a maintenance page on an EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I currently want to display a maintenance page for my web app.

The method I want to follow is to create an EC2 instance and have a static maintenance page in there. When I do bring my webapp down, I want to associate the elastic ip to the new instance.

My question is how do I create a static webpage on the new instance. Any help would be great.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider using a public [Amazon S3 Bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingBucket.html) (standing for Simple Storage Service) instead, if you are only interested in displaying static content.

There is really no point in provisioning a whole EC2 instance only for that.

The documentation is quite comprehensive in regards to creation and configuration of S3 buckets.

[This doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html) in particular describes the steps to follow in order to achieve hosting a static website on an S3 Bucket.